# Error when trying to setFramerate in C++ SFML codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

Hi I am trying to set up a program where a ball will bounce across the renderwindow. I am using SFML c++, iostream, codeblocks(if that makes a difference). I know that I am not anywhere near completion and I may very well be going in the wrong direction. However, one thing I do know for certain is that in order for my program to work I will need to implement sf::Window::setFramerateLimit(60);Or at least that is what I have in my code.

```
include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main(){
RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1500,800), "Bouncing Circle");
sf::Window::setFramerateLimit(60);
```

When ever I try to build/run my program I get an error:

error: cannot call member function 'void sf::Window::setFramerateLimit(unsigned int)' without object|

```
#include<iostream>
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main(){
RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1500,800), "Bouncing Circle");
sf::Window::setFramerateLimit(60);
srand(time(NULL));
int Rand1 = rand()%1500+1;
int Rand2 = rand()%800+1;
int x;
int y;
int BREAK = 1;
sf::CircleShape MyCircle(50);
MyCircle.setPosition(1,1);
MyCircle.setFillColor(sf::Color(500,0,0));

  while (window.isOpen())
 {

    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event));
    {
        if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();

    }
    x = 1;
    y = 1;
    for(int ii = 0; ii < 675; ii++){

    x++;
    y++;
    MyCircle.setPosition(x, y);
    window.draw(MyCircle);
    window.display();
    window.clear();
    BREAK++;
    if(BREAK == 675){
        break;
    }
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest that if you want a quick solution to your problem, remove everything from this write up that is not relevant to the problem itself, such as your school deadline. It distracts the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have `sf::Window::setFramerateLimit(60);` try instead `window.setFramerateLimit(60);` this sets the framerate for your created window (named "window") to 60 frames per second.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I can't believe I hadn't tried that before.

Answer (score 0):

sf::Window::setFramerateLimit(unsigned int); is not a static member function. So you will to have an instance to call it. In a nutshell :

```
int main()
{
  sf::RenderWindow win(sf::VideoMode(500, 500), "Title");

  win.setFramerateLimit(60);
  return 0;
}
```

SFML Documentation warn us about using this function and vsync !